# How to implement the Mach Zehnder Interferometer in Qutip?

Tags: quantum-state, probability, qutip

I was trying to implement the Mach-Zehnder Interferometer with a phase shifter in Qutip but I couldn't nail it. I just want to give two number states as input and at the end see the probability distribution which depends the phase.